# How to include user_id to rendered json with HABTM associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have following models an controller:

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
def show
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   render json: @article
end
```

How to include `user_ids` in renered json?

I have tried:

```
render json: Article.find(params[:id]), include: :user_ids
```

and got

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `serializable_hash' for 1:Fixnum:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it

```
render json: @article.to_json(include: [:users])
```